# RC circuit charging and discharging by square wave not giving a square wave across input on oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, low-pass, function-generator, transient, time-constant

question shifted to [Input across RC circuit is not showing a square wave though the input is a square wave](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/314294/input-across-rc-circuit-is-not-showing-a-square-wave-though-the-input-is-a-squar) as it was unclear

Comment: Start by adding proper paragraphs and punctuation. Then add a schematic of what you are measuring (and actual schematic, not words) with component values.

Comment: Have you got the scope setup wrong - AC coupling? Bad ground?

Comment: Sorry about that @TomCarpenter

Comment: Nope, the scope setup was correct @pjc50

Comment: -1 Unreadable wall of text.

Comment: "he said to change the resistance from 50 ohms to 1k ohms... **it worked** that time".

Answer (score 2):

With the fast edge only being 50% of the input waveform (shown on scope), your generator output resistance is the same value as the R in the RC lowpass.
You have an instantaneous voltage divider for the fast edge.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLeZWA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yeah but later i had added a 1K ohm resistor to see the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful to have included a circuit diagram in the question, to show what you are measuring.

In the absence of that, my guess is that the output impedance of the signal generator is not zero.  So if you put a discharged capacitor across it, then the output voltage drops.  As the capacitor charges, the voltage returns to what it should be.

Comment: It  is a series RC circuit with the output across the capacitor