# Input across RC circuit is not showing a square wave though the input is a square wave

Tags: oscilloscope, low-pass, function-generator, transient

I wanted to observe the transient response of the capacitor so applied a square wave of 205mHz from a function generator as that would allow complete charging and discharging for the capacitor in the circuit below (results came as they were expected), but to compare the difference in input and output signal when i placed the second probe of the oscilloscope across the input it gave the weird waveform below instead of a square wave. Any reason for that ?

R=1 k ohms, C = 470 uF , f = 205 mHz

[image]

Comment: You should have edited the existing question instead of starting a new one.

Comment: You haven't shown where you connected the scope ground. Does your scope show a second trace or are you measuring differential mode?

Comment: Do you really mean 205 mHz?  That's 0.205 Hz.

Comment: @JRE: I though the same thing but \$ RC = 1k \cdot 470m = 470 \; ms \$ so 205 mHz looks OK to give about 10\$ \tau \$.

Comment: Daft question, have you checked the probe compensation? Most scopes usually have a calibration signal to set the compensation.

Comment: Where is the scope grounded?

Comment: Below the capacitor @analogsystemsrf